# Как в kivy создавать вложенные id с «локальной» областью определения?

Tags: python, kivy

Насколько понимаю, ids в kivy имеют "глобальную" область видимости,
то есть по умолчанию можно в kv писать:

```
BoxLayout
    id:a
    BoxLayout
        id:b
```

и получать их через `self.root.ids.a` и `self.root.ids.b` (1)

И нельзя написать:

```
BoxLayout
    id:a
    BoxLayout
        id:a
```

и получать их через `self.root.ids.a` и `self.root.ids.a.ids.a` (2).

В определенных ситуациях это может быть полезно.
Возможно ли в kivy сделать что-то похожее на (2)?

Answer (score 0):

Вот кое-что набросал(ну как я понял)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<A>:
    Label:
        id:a
        text:'a'

<B>:
    Label:
        id:b
        text:'b'
''')



class A(BoxLayout):
    pass

class B(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        box=BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(Button(text='test',on_press=self.testing))
        box.add_widget(A())
        box.add_widget(B())
        return box

    def testing(self,instance):
        try:
            print(self.ids.a.text)
            print(self.ids.b.text)
        except:
            print('не достается(((. наверное/точно они просто находятся в недосягаемом списке')


TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Вопрос не совсем про это. Мне нужен пример кода, который бы содержал кострукцию типа self.root.ids.a.ids.a

Comment: Имеется ввиду возможность из текущего класса(возможно лучше сказать родителя) вызвать id других классов(родителей)? Наверное не это))) Возможно как-то перефразировать вопрос?

Comment: Если вызвать ids так как вы написали, то будет ошибка. Вообще с помощью вас я узнал, что вот эти id должны быть уникальными, потому как при добавлении виджета по id добавление происходит в последнем боксе. Если интересно могу показать код.

Comment: Некоторые примеры использования id: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908449/python-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-kivy/908526#908526)

Comment: вот у вас в примере:
    Label:
        id:a
        text:'a'
а надо:
    Label:
        id:a
        Label:
            id:a

То есть внутри виджета 'А' с id 'a' есть виджет 'B' с id 'a'
Интересует возможность/невозможность такого в kivy.

Comment: Нет, если внутри одного id другой id, то он будет так же доступен как и первый, тоесть они все принадлежат к одному родительскому классу. Если посмотреть ссылку, которую я привел выше там показано, что список id'шников это словарь, а в словаре одинаковых ключей быть не может - они (эти ключи) просто перезаписываются и поэтому id должны быть уникальными. Если обращаться так как вы хотите то приложение завершиться с ошибкой.