# python проблема с классами (kivy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```
import random

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class Player():
    """
    Player's stats and moves
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.hp = 250
        self.damage = 10
        self.crit = 15
        self.mod = 2

    def start_game(self, *args):
        #init players
        player1 = Player()
        player2 = Player()

        self.player1_hp.text = str(player1.hp)

class root(FloatLayout, Player):
    pass

class app(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Knights duel rev 1.0"
        return root()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app().run()
```

и .kv файл

```
<root>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height
    Button:
        id: begin
        text: 'Start'
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.01, 'center_y': 0.94}
        color: .12, .66, .95, 1
        background_color: (.53, .89, .38, 1)
        background_normal: ""
        size_hint: .1, .1
        font_size: self.height - dp(25)

        on_press: root.start_game()

    Label:
        id: player1_hp
        text: '0'
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии кнопки выдает ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'root' object has no attribute 'player1_hp'
```

хотя мой класс root() наследуется от класса Player().Или .kv не умеет в наследование(в чем я сомневаюсь), что, в свою очередь, заставит переписывать все методы в класс root(), что будет противоречить нормальной логике проекта.

Сделал даже отдельный метод в root() и перепривязал к нему кнопку - ошибка та же.

Comment: А попробуйте так `class root(Player, FloatLayout):` или у `root` в `init`'е пропишите `FloatLayout.__init__(self)` `Player.__init__(self)`

Comment: Крашится на этапе запуска

Comment: Просто крашится, без ошибок? Крашится для обоих предложенных мною вариантов?

Comment: Да, приложение не отвечает. Пробовал и так и так. К тому же пробовал еще и через super() - результат тот же, насколько я понял в root() вообще лучше ничего не класть.

Comment: Запустите под отладчиком чтобы понять на каком моменте возникает проблема

Comment: По моему нужно написать так self.ids.player1_hp.text = str(player1.hp)

Comment: Ещё в root нужно: def __init__(self,**kwargs): super().__init__(**kwargs) прописать.

Comment: Так заработало..Так работать стоит со всеми id или у меня какое-то исключение? И можете ответить отдельным сообщением, я вопрос отмечу как решенный.

Comment: Хм. Мне кажется немного странным в классе Player создавать экземпляры этого же класса player=Player(). Возможно здесь ещё ошибка. А если показать что должно быть на выходе может понятней будет?

Comment: Да, это можно вынести в отдельный класс, скажем game(), либо создавать сразу же при выполнении скрипта.

Comment: А ещё player. Эта переменная доступна только внутри функции. Вне функции вы к ней не обратитесь. Все же добавление экземпляров лучше, как по мне, производить в каком-то главном классе. В этом главном классе нужно не player, а self.player - так она будет доступна вне функции, но все же внутри класса где она объявлена.

Comment: @АлексейОсинный Да, уже столкнулся с проблемами ввиду локальности переменных. Пришлось переделать на:    `def start_game(self, *args):  
        #init players     
        global player1, player2  

        player1 = Player()  
        player2 = Player()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот некотрые примеры как использовать id:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Builder.load_string('''
<A>:
    Button:
        text:'test'
        on_press:root.testing()
    BoxLayout:
        id:a
        Label:
            text:'Первый'
    BoxLayout:
        id:b
        Label:
            text:'Второй'
''')



class A(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def testing(self):
        try:
            #вот сейчас произойдет печать всех id этого класса
            print('Все айдишники класса А')
            print(self.ids)
            #id должен быть оригинальным иначе при повторении он будет один
            #и изменения производимые по id будут применяться к последнему виджету
            #которому был присвоен не уникальный id
            print()
            #я могу обращаться по id и по детям, но по детям немного не правильно
            #например я могу достать лейбл бокса "а" по индексу 0
            print('В боксе с айди "а" по индексу "0" есть лейбл с текстом:')
            print(self.ids.a.children[0].text)
            print()

        except:
            print('не получается(')


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        box=BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(A())
        return box


TestApp().run()
```